# Meteor.js Load Persisted Option in Select Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have a **Plataforms** collection in MongoDB, and a form in which I can persist new **Projects** ( one project have one plataform ), and the options are generated in a html select like this:

```
{{#each plataforms}}
    <option>{{name}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

Which gives me a html select where I choose one option and click "save button". That works fine and I can persist the selected option by name ( value = option text ).

My problem is when I want to edit my "Project". I can load all the persisted data which are single text inputs, but I cant load the previous persisted option in the select. It always gives me the first option of the select input, and not the previous persisted selected option.

How can I achieve this? Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
$('#mySelect option[value="somevalue"]').prop('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set selected on the 'persisted' option:

```
<option selected="selected">
```

Comment: I know that but I can't determine which option is actually selected in a Spacebars/Handlebars template, even if have the persisted option name, cause in Spacebars templates I don't have a "equals" comparator...